# rewrite Url parameters doesn't work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I willing to rewrite the url with a htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^low/?\?id=([0-9]+)$    index.php?serv=5&id=$1    [NC,L] #doesnt work
```

But I don't success to redirect the parameters from the first to the changed url. It throw me an error 404

but if I simply do: `RewriteRule    ^low/?$    index.php?serv=5    [NC,L]`, it does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule`. Besides you don't need to capture the query string as that will be passed over to target if you use `QSA` flag as `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^low/$ index.php?serv=5&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```